# Change custom combobox style dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Hi I have a common `Combobox` style defined as below in a WPF project.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" >
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
    <!--<Setter Property="MaxDropDownHeight" Value="310"/>-->
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="mainBor">
                    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ahf:ComboKeyDownBehavior/>
                    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Grid.Column="2" Focusable="false" ClickMode="Press" 
                                        IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                            <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                                    <ahf:ComboToggleButtonMouseDown/>
                                </interactivity:EventTrigger>
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </ToggleButton>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="5,3,23,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Visible"/>

                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,19,0" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Hidden" IsTabStop="False"
                                    BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                            <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                                    <ahf:ComboDropDownTriggerAction/>
                                </interactivity:EventTrigger>
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </TextBox>

                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                    </Border.Background>
                                </Border>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" TargetName="mainBor"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderColorOnFocus}" TargetName="mainBor"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderColorOnFocus}" TargetName="mainBor"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderColorOnFocus}" TargetName="mainBor"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--<Trigger SourceName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Popup" Property="IsOpen" Value="False"/>
                    </Trigger>-->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13.333"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Myriad Pro"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Now Here's how I have used `Combobox` in a window.

```xml
<ComboBox MinWidth="220"
        SelectedValue="{Binding SupplierConfirmed,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        x:Name="cbOrderConfirmation" SelectionChanged="cbOrderConfirmation_SelectionChanged"
        GotFocus="CbOrderConfirmation_GotFocus" Tag="{Binding}"
        Foreground="{Binding PowderCoatedOrderId, Converter={StaticResource PowdercoaterColorConverter}, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding LstOrderConfirmStatus}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="UID" Width="220" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
```

Now what I want to do is to bind background color of `Combobox` based on some value like I have done for `Foreground`. I have tried binding background color the same way foreground is bound but it isn't working. I don't know what else to do.

What should I change in common style to make background work dynamically based on some value ?

Comment: You currently don't use the Background property (as `{TemplateBinding Background}`) in your control template.

Comment: Apparently you set the **Backgroud** of the combobox from back end using the name of control. I recommend you to use the style defined in the top of your code and add setter property for **Background**, then bind the desired color for value of it.

Comment: @KlausGütter It worked with {TemplateBinding Background}Thank You !